# Mapbox GL sort overlapping circles by radius

Tags: mapbox-gl

I'm trying to display circles with Mapbox GL that are very close and sometimes they overlap. I would like the circles to overlap according to their size (radius), from the biggest to the smallest, so that they will all be visible on map. Is there a way to do it?

I made a simple example to illustrate the problem I'm facing. One can see that the circle with the biggest radius is on top of the others.

```
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-31.640625,
        31.952162238024975
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "value": 5
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-31.640625,
        31.952162238024975
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "value": 10
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-31.640625,
        31.952162238024975
      ]
    }
  }]
};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
  center: [-30, 33],
  zoom: 3
});

map.on("load", function() {

  map.addSource('point', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": data
  });

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "point",
    "source": "point",
    "type": "circle",
    "paint": {
      "circle-color": "#FFFF00",
      "circle-stroke-width": 1,
      "circle-stroke-color": "#000",
      "circle-radius": {
        property: 'value',
        stops: [
          [2, 10],
          [10, 30],
        ]
      }
    }
  });

})
```

Complete example in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zorgdevalmont/5ch1aj52/3/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mapbox-gl renders the features in the order it receives them, you could also sort the features in your feature collection prior to adding it to the map:

```
data.features.sort((a,b) => b.properties.value - a.properties.value);
```

This may not always be feasible and I'm not 100% sure the feature rendering order in mapbox is by design and will always be preserved, but it seems to work in your example.

Updated JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ch1aj52/7/

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question, I think you want to treat each circle as it's own layer and render them on top of each other like this:

```
var data1 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "value": 2
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-31.640625,
        31.952162238024975
      ]
    }
  }]};

  var data2 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "value": 5
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-31.640625,
        31.952162238024975
      ]
    }
  }]};
  var data3 = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "value": 10
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-31.640625,
        31.952162238024975
      ]
    }
  }]
};

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
  center: [-30, 33],
  zoom: 3
});

map.on("load", function() {

  map.addSource('point1', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": data1
  });

   map.addSource('point2', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": data2
  });

   map.addSource('point3', {
    "type": "geojson",
    "data": data3
  });

   map.addLayer({
    "id": "point3",
    "source": "point3",
    "type": "circle",
    "paint": {
        "circle-color": "#FFFF00", 
      "circle-stroke-width":1,
      "circle-stroke-color": "#000",
      "circle-radius": {
        property: 'value',
        stops: [
          [2, 10],
          [10, 30],
        ]
      }
    }
  });

 map.addLayer({
    "id": "point2",
    "source": "point2",
    "type": "circle",
    "paint": {
        "circle-color": "#FFFF00", 
      "circle-stroke-width":1,
      "circle-stroke-color": "#000",
      "circle-radius": {
        property: 'value',
        stops: [
          [2, 10],
          [10, 30],
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "point1",
    "source": "point1",
    "type": "circle",
    "paint": {
        "circle-color": "#FFFF00", 
      "circle-stroke-width":1,
      "circle-stroke-color": "#000",
      "circle-radius": {
        property: 'value',
        stops: [
          [2, 10],
          [10, 30],
        ]
      }
    }
  });
})
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/5ch1aj52/6/

Let me know if thats what you were after?

Comment: I know this is a super old answer now, but I just wanted to say that this solution is incredibly inefficient as each layer provides another level of complexity and computation to the map. You should strive for fewer layers and sources, only splitting them up when file sizes become too large to serve quickly.